# PicSimlab 0.7.5 version is shutting down very frequently within 1 minute

Tags: c, mplab, hex-file

picsimlab tool version 0.7.5 tool is closing down within 1minute after opening the tool in windows 10.
I tried uninstalling and installing again, still facing same issue.
I am trying to load hex file generated by running C project in MPLAB X IDE V5.35
I tried same picsimlab in ubuntu20.04 , which is running fine there, in windows its closing very frequently

Answer (score 0):

just re-download the file from official website, i downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/picsim/files/v0.7.5/picsimlab_0_7_5_win64_setup.exe/download).
and then re-installed, working fine.
May be file downloaded earlier is corrupted.